# .Net-Core Proj - MSBuild failing to copy to output folder

Tags: tfs, .net-core, msbuild, command, tfsbuild

Trying to build to .NET-Core Project from TFS, the build is failing because the following command`s not working, failing to copy built files to output folder. The command is working fine for a .Net Framework project, not working only for .Net Core Project. Kindly check.

It works fine with basic command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin>MSBuild.exe "C:\TFSFolder\Builds\GUID\DotnetCoreProject.sln"  /p:OutDir="C:\TFSFolder\Builds\39\b\DotnetCoreProject\\"
```

Non-working Command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin>MSBuild.exe "C:\TFSFolder\Builds\GUID\DotnetCoreProject.sln" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\TFSFolder\Builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.126.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=2c81e6a8-374d-4a65-91ba-418b04505e77|SolutionDir=C:\TFSFolder\Builds\GUID\"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\TFSFolder\Builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.126.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:OutDir="C:\TFSFolder\Builds\39\b\DotnetCoreProject\\" /t:Restore /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_fa1cf861-541e-47b2-b0f3-8c684de5500a_build_22138_1486294"
```

It just need to copy built files to the output folder path mentioned. I could only guess that the dll mentioned isnt supported, kindly check and help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only restoring and cleaning the project because you specify `/t:Clean` and `/t:Restore`.

Use `-restore -t:Rebuild` instead.

Also note that you normally don't want the output directory contents of a .NET Core project for deployment but rather its publish output. For this use the Publish target on the project instead:

`-restore -t:Publish theproject.csproj -p:PublishDir=artifact\location`

Comment: Had to use '/t:Restore' for fixing an error, it was about package asset file. Also about publishing, it`s quiet not understandable,  how will it work without building? Please be informed that this is configured on tfs. Please be more clear on how can this be configured on tfs for publishing?

Comment: The publish target internally depends on the build target. TFS / AzureDevops also has .NET Core build tasks that you could use. The Visual Studio build task can also be configured with different parameters.